# Programming language based on generative AI?

Tags: programming, artificial-intelligence, llm

ChatGPT and generative AIs have been in a lot of uses lately. With Github's copilot being as closely integrated into the development experience as it can get. Or is it?

Is there a whole programming language that's actually based on generative AI? Like this:

```
const dinner = promptAI('What would you like for dinner today?')
if (evalAI(`Is ${dinner} non-veg?`)) {
  promptAI('Sorry, veg only')
} else {
  const missingIngredients = evalAI(`Find out from the list "inventory.txt" if there are any missing ingredients for ${dinner}`)
  promptAI(`Great choice! Can you get ${missingIngredients}? while you're out?`)
}
```

Notice the functions `promptAI` & `evalAI` they allow the programmer to code in the logic using simple english statements.

Is there a programming language, or a library for any existing programming language that allows you to code like this?

Requirements:

- Be a programming language, or a library for a programming language
- Generative AI able to carry out logic that integrates seamlessly with the language
- OS: Any (Desktop)
- Price: Any

Answer (score 1):

many projects exist on github that provide programmatic access to Chatbots. I can't and don't want to list them all.

For example [simpleaichat](https://github.com/minimaxir/simpleaichat)

> Newer versions of ChatGPT also support "function calling", but the
> real benefit of that feature is the ability for ChatGPT to support
> structured input and/or output, which now opens up a wide variety of
> applications! simpleaichat streamlines the workflow to allow you to
> just pass an input_schema and/or an output_schema.
>
> You can construct a schema using a pydantic BaseModel.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

ai = AIChat(
    console=False,
    save_messages=False,  # with schema I/O, messages are never saved
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
    params={"temperature": 0.0},
)

class get_event_metadata(BaseModel):
    """Event information"""

    description: str = Field(description="Description of event")
    city: str = Field(description="City where event occured")
    year: int = Field(description="Year when event occured")
    month: str = Field(description="Month when event occured")
```

```
# returns a dict, with keys ordered as in the schema
ai("First iPhone announcement", output_schema=get_event_metadata)
{'description': 'The first iPhone was announced by Apple Inc.',
 'city': 'San Francisco',
 'year': 2007,
 'month': 'January'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not an entire programming language , however, in Microsoft's ["Semantic Kernel" SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel) which is available for many popular languages, the authors call those constructs that you (presumably) describe a ["Semantic Function"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/semantic-kernel/prompts/your-first-prompt): "Creating a prompt that detects the intent of a user".

Check out the tutorial "How Business Thinkers Can Start Building AI Plugins With Semantic Kernel" on [deeplearning.ai](https://learn.deeplearning.ai) which emphasizes these aspects more than the official documentation.

The authors argue that programmers probably want to mix semantic functions with classic "native" functions anyway.